# Add audio controls to multiple music files in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift development and I'm trying to play/pause on lock screen multiple audio files using:

```
remoteControlReceived
```

But it is only allowing me to add it once meaning I can only control one audio file but I'd like 2 other audio files to have play/pause enabled on lock screen.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
// Playback controls

override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let event = event {
        if event.type == .remoteControl {
            switch event.subtype {
            case .remoteControlPlay: audioPlayer.play()
            case . remoteControlPause: audioPlayer.pause()

            default: print("Done")
            }
        }
    }
}

override func remoteControlReceived0(with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let event = event {
        if event.type == .remoteControl {
            switch event.subtype {
            case .remoteControlPlay: audioPlayer1.play()
            case . remoteControlPause: audioPlayer1.pause()
            default: print("Done")
            }
        }
    }
}

func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let event = event {
        if event.type == .remoteControl {
            switch event.subtype {
            case .remoteControlPlay: audioPlayer2.play()
            case . remoteControlPause: audioPlayer2.pause()
            default: print("Done")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it is only allowing me to add it once meaning I can only control one audio file but I'd like 2 other audio files to have play/pause enabled on lock screen

You can’t. It references only the now playing item.